# Could not find or load main class Alice

Tags: java

I have a simple java program with class name alice (rechecked)

Class Alice uses a few classes from commons-codec package. When I try to run it, I get the following error.

Please suggest where I am going wrong; I have been struggling with this for over an now.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bvh9b.png)

Comment: please show your code and include the error message as text, not as screenshot.

Comment: You're missing all classpath statements. This has been well explained in prior [similar questions](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=site:stackoverflow.com+java+could+not+find+or+load+main+class), and I encourage you to search first before asking what is likely to be a common question.